# Why is this A0 character appearing in my HTML::Element output?

Tags: perl, encoding

I'm parsing an HTML document with a couple Perl modules: [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-TreeBuilder) and [HTML::Element](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Element). For some reason whenever the content of a tag is just `&nbsp;`, which is to be expected, it gets returned by HTML::Element as a strange character I've never seen before:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2acca201ab.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2acca201ab.jpg)

I can't copy the character so can't Google it, couldn't find it in character map, and strangely when I search with a regular expression, `\w` finds it. When I convert the returned document to ANSI or UTF-8 it disappears altogether. I couldn't find any info on it in the HTML::Element documentation either.

How can I detect and replace this character with something more useful like `null` and how should I deal with strange characters like this in the future?

Comment: the image link has rotten

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The character is `"\xa0"` (i.e. 160), which is the standard Unicode translation for `&nbsp;`.  (That is, it's Unicode's non-breaking space.)  You should be able to remove them with `s/\xa0/ /g` if you like.

Answer (score 8):

The character is [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Encodings) which is what `&nbsp;` stands for:

> In word processing and digital typesetting, a non-breaking space (" ") (also called no-break space, non-breakable space (NBSP), hard space, or fixed space) is a space character that prevents an automatic line break at its position. In some formats, including HTML, it also prevents consecutive whitespace characters from collapsing into a single space.
>
> In HTML, the common non-breaking space, which is the same width as the ordinary space character, is encoded as   or  . In Unicode, it is encoded as `U+00A0`.